# Binding properties of a lists list in Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm trying to bind properties from a list that contains 2 other lists inside of it, but for some reason it doesnt display anything on my datagrid.

As you can see below I create an observableCollection, and when I debug, the list has all the required properties(The ones im trying to add in the XAML binding section) but it doesnt work for some reason.

**The class that initializes the datagrid**

```
        private CategoryServiceClient quizClient = new CategoryServiceClient();
        private IList<Category> quizList;

        public QuizWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadUserData();
        }

        private void LoadUserData()
        {
            // The GetCategoriesQuestionAnswers method has a list of categories with a 
            // list of questions and a list of answers
            quizList = new ObservableCollection<Category>(quizClient.GetCategoriesQuestionsAnswers());
            try
            {
                quizDatagrid.ItemsSource = quizList;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                throw;

            }
        }
```

**XAML**

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="quizDatagrid" CanUserAddRows="False" Margin="10,90,0,10" ClipboardCopyMode="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="698">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding id}" Header="Category ID" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding name}" Header="Category Name" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding category.question.id}" Header="Question ID" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding category.question.description}" Header="Question Description" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding category.question.answer.id}" Header="Answer ID" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding category.question.answer.description}" Header="Answer Description" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding category.question.answer.isCorrect}" Header="Is Correct" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding category.question.answer.pointAmount}" Header="Point Amount" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

This is the Category Class

```
public class Category
{
    [DataMember]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int amount { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Quiz quiz { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Question> question { get; set; }

    public Category()
    { 
        question = new List<Question>();
    }
}
```

**This is my Question class**

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class Question
{

    [DataMember]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string description { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Category category { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool isAnswered { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }

    public Question()
    {
        Answers = new List<Answer>();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your `Category` class look like? I am guessing it doesn't have a valid property of `id` or `category.question.id`

Comment: I added the Category class, amount and Quiz isn't used anywhere so just ignore that :)

Comment: Oh btw, the "id" and "name" bindings work, they display the Category ID and the Category Name

Comment: If you write `quizList[0].category.question.id` in your code, you will of course see the compiler throw an error. Because `Category` does not contain a property called `category`, and `List<Question>` does not contain a property called id. You need the bindings to match exactly how it would in the code... so you could write a binding for `id` because `quizList[0].id` is valid. Or bind `quiz.id` because `quizList[0].quiz.id` is valid. Do you see the problem now?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm trying to understand it, but you are right, question[0].description worked for me, however ID is 0 for all rows when i try: question[0].id , guess I made an error somewhere. I'm trying to analyze what youre saying over and over again atm :P

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that question[0].answer[0].description should work as well??? But it doesnt, am I that dumb :(..

Comment: I can't remember if you can bind to an array with `{Binding question[0].answer[0].description}`... you might need to create a property that returns `question[0].answer[0].description` if you want to display that value in a bound field. You could also add the proper security checks if you do that, such as checking for empty arrays.

Comment: Hmm okay, I guess I'll try some stuff out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataGrid will only add a row for each item in its ItemsSource (which is an ObservableCollection in this case), i.e. you will get a row per *Category* object and not a row per Question object within a category.

It is not hierarchical. If you want to display all questions that belong to a specific category in the same DataGrid you could use an DataGridTemplateColumn that contains a nested DataGrid:

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="quizDatagrid" CanUserAddRows="False" Margin="10,90,0,10" 
              ClipboardCopyMode="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="698">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding id}" Header="Category ID" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding name}" Header="Category Name" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding question}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding id}" Header="Question ID" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding description}" Header="Question Description" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding answer.id}" Header="Answer ID" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding answer.description}" Header="Answer Description" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding answer.isCorrect}" Header="Is Correct" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding answer.pointAmount}" Header="Point Amount" />
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

You can display the *first* question of a category in the same top-level DataGrid by binding to the first index in the question List in each Category object:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="quizDatagrid" CanUserAddRows="False" Margin="10,90,0,10" ClipboardCopyMode="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="698">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding id}" Header="Category ID" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding name}" Header="Category Name" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding question[0].id}" Header="Question ID" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding question[0].description}" Header="Question Description" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding question[0].answer.id}" Header="Answer ID" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding question[0].answer.description}" Header="Answer Description" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding question[0].answer.isCorrect}" Header="Is Correct" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding question[0].answer.pointAmount}" Header="Point Amount" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**Edit:** You set the ItemsSource of the DataGrid to an ObservableCollection. Each Category has a collection of questions. And each Question has a collection of answers. The DataGrid will render a row per Category only. You can only display a single question and a single answer on this level:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding question[0].id}" Header="Question ID" />
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding question[0].description}" Header="Question Description" />
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding question[0].Answers[0].id}" Header="Answer ID" />
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding question[0].Answers[0].description}" Header="Answer Description
```

Comment: Umm, I just get An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Value cannot be null.

When I do it like that.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible sample of your issue including all relevant classes and sample data if you need any further help. The main point is that a DataGrid only binds to the "first level" of data.

Comment: Im currently done coding for tonight, but I appreciate the help, Im simply confused because youre saying that it only Works on the "first level" but somehow i can Still bind to the question List properties

Comment: You can display the first question of a category in the same top-level DataGrid by binding to the first index in the question List<Question> in each Category object. See my edited answer for an example.

Comment: I can't seem to display anything for answer, but question and category work like that

Comment: You haven't posted the definition of your Question class but since you bind to question[0].answer it is supposed to have an "answer" property that returns an Answer object with id, description, isCorrect and pointAmount properties. But again, you should provide a reproducible sample if want people to be able to point out what you are doing wrong. It's hard (or rather impossible) to guess how your classes are defined and how your data looks like.

Comment: It is the same thing there. You set the ItemsSource of the DataGrid to an ObservableCollection<Category>. Each Category has a collection of questions. And each Question has a collection of answers. The DataGrid will render a row per Category only. You can only display a single question and a single answer on this level. See my edited answer. The thing is that you cannot expect the DataGrid to render all categories, questions and answers for you in a flat structure when you set the ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection<Category> because it doesn't work this way.

Comment: I would have sworn I did just that last night and it didnt work out... but now it does.. Thank you.